# When running the Angular dev server, why are my API calls being returned with a 301 status code?

Tags: angular, azure

I have a .NET Core API hosted in Azure.  When running my Angular UI locally (version 8) I want to point API requests to my app service running in Azure.  To do this, I set up my Angular proxy.conf.json file like so:

```js
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://my-app.azurewebsites.net",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug",
    "changeOrigin": "true"
  },
```

When I run the UI locally and attempt to log in I'm seeing these 3 requests Chrome's network debugger:

```
[General]
Request URL: http://localhost:4200/api/account/login
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 301 Moved Permanently

[Response Headers]
location: https://my-app.azurewebsites.net/api/account/login
server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0

---

[General]
Request URL: https://my-app.azurewebsites.net/api/account/login
Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 204 No Content

[Response Headers]
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200

---

[General]
Request URL: https://my-app.azurewebsites.net/api/account/login
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 404 Not Found
```

What's particularly odd is that my login request (as called from my UI) is a POST, not a GET.

I've configured Angular's dev-server proxy in many projects and never seen this before.  Feels like I'm missing something obvious..

Answer (score 3):

I forgot that I had recently updated my Azure app to by "HTTPS Only"! Since my proxy was configured to send traffic to the "http", the Azure server was returning a 301, as it should.

Once I changed my proxy config file to account for that everything worked as expected:

```js
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "https://my-app.azurewebsites.net", <-- https now
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug",
    "changeOrigin": "true"
  },
```

Knowing this, the details for the 3 HTTP requests that I saw in Chrome makes more sense - I can see Azure is returning a 301 redirecting me to the same route, but with "https" this time.